# Dynamic cluster for main computer use

Tags: networking

In January our home network is being upgraded so that each bedroom is on its own sub network and i was wondering two things.

- Could i create a dynamic cluster so that i could add or remove nodes automatically without having to edit anything.
- And would it be viable to use this as a main computer instead of a separate desktop (I already have one but if i made a cluster i would be the server)

Comment: You have provided no information on what the individual computers are, or how the will be used in a cluster.

Comment: Hi James, can you include mor information on what you mean by "Cluster" and how your home network is to be segregated?  Individual subnets for individual rooms doesn't in any way mean segregation without the addition of something like ACLs or VLANs. If you can expand and tell us more about your design we can better answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kinda, but you probably don't want to unless you have non-standard tasks for home use.

Clusters require special software (and often homogeneous hardware), so you can't just connect many PCs together an get a single "better" one for browsing the web, kid's homework, and playing games. For the most part, unless you are an infrastructure engineer creating a redundant load balanced service, or a scientist crunching numbers, or doing advanced visualization tasks, there is little likelihood that a multi-node architecture is a wise choice.

Even if you have home-server tasks like filesharing/NAS, HTTP applications, DNS, etc, none of them will benefit from a multi-node architecture at a home-sized load or home-sized level of reliability. your home's power won't approach 99.999% uptime, so designing an architecture for that seems silly.